# How to add background for only icons in bottom navigation bar android?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I want to add only background for icon not all the item background.

Here is my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/surface_container_lowest"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/Theme.FarmKeep.TextAppearance.SemiBold.LabelSmallProminent"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/Theme.FarmKeep.TextAppearance.Regular.LabelSmall"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/on_surface"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/selector_bottom_nav_background
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main"/>
```

The background fills the icon and text, so how can I just fill only the icon like the attached image?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu from the picture is from `material3` style, so your app theme or at least bottom_navigation_main theme has to have parent theme from `Theme.Material3` e.g. `Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar`. With this it should work fine, just remove `app:itemBackground="@drawable/selector_bottom_nav_background"` line.

If you don't want to change whole app theme, add `android:theme="@style/Theme.Material3.DayNight"` to set theme just for the navigation, it should look like this:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/surface_container_lowest"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/Theme.FarmKeep.TextAppearance.SemiBold.LabelSmallProminent"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/Theme.FarmKeep.TextAppearance.Regular.LabelSmall"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/on_surface"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Material3.DayNight"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!-- res/drawable/icon_selector.xml -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#FF6200EE"/> <!-- Background color for the selected state -->
                    <size android:width="24dp" android:height="24dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_your_icon" android:gravity="center"/>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_your_icon"/> <!-- Default icon -->
</selector>
```

Other layout:

```
 <!-- res/menu/menu_main.xml -->
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_selector"
            android:title="@string/title_home" />
        <!-- Other items -->
    </menu>
```